# how to bind request body in Finch

Tags: web-services, scala, finagle, finch

Here is the code to bind request param to the router.

```
val testReader: Endpoint[Test] = Endpoint.derive[Test].fromParams
val test: Endpoint[String] = post("test" ? testReader) { t : Test => {
    Created("OK")
  }}
```

I am using the method `fromParams`. This method can bind request parameters in a very cool way. However, I dont konw which similiar way I can  bind **request body** in the finch

Many thanks in advance

Answer (score 9, accepted):

For the sake of providing a complete working example I'll assume a case class like this:

```
case class Test(foo: Int, bar: String)
```

And some requests like this:

```
import com.twitter.finagle.http.{ Method, Request, RequestBuilder }
import com.twitter.io.{ Buf, Reader }

val queryParamPost = Request(Method.Post, "/test?foo=1&bar=whatever")

val testJsonBuf = Buf.Utf8("""{ "foo": 1, "bar": "whatever" }""")

val bodyPost = RequestBuilder().url("http://localhost:8080/test").buildPost(testJsonBuf)
```

Now when you write the following…

```
import io.finch._

val testParams: Endpoint[Test] = Endpoint.derive[Test].fromParams
val test: Endpoint[Test] = post("test" ? testParams) { test: Test =>
  Created(test)
}
```

What's happening is that Finch is using generic derivation (powered by Shapeless) to determine (at compile time) how to parse the query params as a `Test`. You can then test the endpoint like this:

```
import io.finch.circe._
import io.circe.generic.auto._

test.toService.apply(queryParamPost).onSuccess { response =>
  println(s"$response: ${ response.contentString }")
}
```

Which will print:

```
Response("HTTP/1.1 Status(201)"): {"foo":1,"bar":"whatever"}
```

Here I'm using [Circe](https://github.com/travisbrown/circe)'s generic derivation to automatically encode the "created" `Test` as JSON for the response.

You can also use Circe to derive a reader for the request body:

```
val testBody: Endpoint[Test] = body.as[Test]
val test2: Endpoint[Test] = post("test" :: testBody) { test: Test =>
  Created(test)
}
```

This is almost exactly the same as `test` above, but we're using `body` to get an `Endpoint[String]` that will read the request body and then `as` to specify that we want the content parsed as JSON and decoded as a `Test` value. We can test this new version like this:

```
test2.toService.apply(bodyPost).onSuccess { response =>
  println(s"$response: ${ response.contentString }")
}
```

And we'll get the answer we expect again.

In general when you want to read a certain kind of information of an incoming request, you'll use one of the basic `Endpoint`s provided by Finch (see [the docs](https://github.com/finagle/finch/blob/master/docs/endpoint.md) for a more complete list), and then use methods like `as`, `map`, etc. on the `Endpoint` to turn it into the shape you need.

Comment: I didnt realize /, ? and :: are actually doing the same thing :)

Comment: @Travis Brown Can you edit your answer and add a short example with custom decoder? In my use case, `Test` has a field of type `scalaz.Maybe`. Having it as `Option` works, but how can I make it work with `Maybe` (which I prefer over `Option` for a couple of reasons)? I keep getting "Attempt to decode value on failed cursor".

Comment: @slouc That's probably worth a new question (which I'd be happy to answer). I'd probably define a single generic instance for `scalaz.Maybe[A: Decoder]`, but need more detail.

Comment: @Travis Brown Yeah, I figured it should probably be a new question, but I was a bit lazy. Anyways, I managed to solve it in the meantime. I posted a question and answered it myself; not sure if SO admins consider this ok or not, but if it's ok then let's keep it for others. Please feel free to add something from your side: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42209195/circe-decoder-for-scalaz-maybe/42209211#42209211